# How to use search and replace from second occurrence

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am working on a script where I need to replace from second occurrence. I tried with the below code but output is not matching with expected.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stg = "varun.kumar.ms.sri";
$stg =~ 's/\./\.x/2g';
print "$stg\n";
```

Expected output:

```
varun.kumar.xms.xsri
```

Actual output:

```
varun.kumar.ms.sri
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your substitution operator uses incorrect syntax.  You should not use single quotes around `s///`, and `/2` is not a recognized modifier.

Secondly, I don't know of a way to do this in a single regex.  But, there is a way to do it by splitting the string into 2 pieces, then doing the substitution on the 2nd piece only:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stg = "varun.kumar.ms.sri";
my ($start, $rest) = split /\./, $stg, 2;
$rest =~ s/\./\.x/g;
$stg = "$start.$rest";
print "$stg\n";
```

Prints:

```
varun.kumar.xms.xsri
```

This splits the string into 2 pieces based on the 1st `.`, using the [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) **LIMIT** of 2.  Then it globally replaces all `.` with `.x` in the 2nd piece.  Finally, it reconstructs the full string.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that's contained entirely within a substitution:

```perl
$stg =~ s{
   \. \K .*            # Replace what comes after the first `.`.
}{
   $& =~ s/\.\K/x/gr   # Transform the substring to replace.
}xse;
```

Comment: Hi Champ, its not working while I am trying this code. What is the mistake I am doing.
`
# Replace what comes after the first `.`.
# Transform the substring to replace.
my $stg = "varun.kumar.ms.sri";
$stg=~s{\. \K .*}{$& =~ s/\.\K/x/gr}se;
print $stg;
`

Comment: Your second answer working fine.

Comment: /x was missing.

Comment: Apologies for the chilly question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Can also use the [*SKIP](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(*SKIP)-(*SKIP:NAME)) verb

```
$stg =~ s/^[^.]*\. (*SKIP)(*F) | \.\K/x/xg'
```

A command-line program for a ready test

```
perl -wE'say "varun.kumar.ms.sri" =~ s/^[^.]*\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\.\K/x/rg'
```

---

The above is for "*from second occurrence*" -- if that can change add a quantifier

```
$stg =~ s/^(?:[^.]+\.){1} (*SKIP)(*F) | \.\K/x/xg'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to `split` as the earlier answer suggests, then you might as well use the following:

```perl
my @parts = split( /\./, $stg, -1 );
$_ = "x$_" for @parts[ 2 .. $#parts ];
$stg = join( ".", @parts );
```

Bonus: Unlike toolic's solution, this one doesn't warn and fail if the string contains no `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution without doing a split:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stg = "varun.kumar.ms.sri";

# Find the first dot. A global match in Boolean context finds them one
# at a time. We exit after the first, leaving the match position just
# after the first dot.
while ( $stg =~ m/\./g ) { last };

# Do the replacement on the substring that begins after the first dot.
# Since substr() is an lvalue subroutine, the underlying string gets
# modified.
substr( $stg, pos $stg ) =~ s/\./.x/g;


print "$stg\n"; # prints 'varun.kumar.xms.xsri'
```

Comment: Void context is good enough for setting `pos`, so `while ( $stg =~ m/\./g ) { last };` can be simplified to `$stg =~ /\./g;`.

Comment: `\G` matches at the `pos`, so `substr( $stg, pos $stg ) =~ s/\./.x/g;` could also be written as `$stg =~ s/\G[^.]*\.\K/x/g;`

Answer (score -3):

To insert a character (x) before the 3th word in one *[regex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-regex-cheat-sheet/)* you could use: `s/^(\w+\.\w+\.)/$1x/;`.

So the changed script:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $stg = "varun.kumar.ms.sri";
$stg =~ s/^(\w+\.\w+\.)/$1x/;
print "$stg\n";
```

Will result in:

```
varun.kumar.xms.sri
```

Comment: That does not produce the the desired output.

Comment: Yes it does, i've just checked again. What output did you get?

Comment: It produces `varun.kumar.xms.sri` like you said it does. That is not the desired output.

Comment: Ah I see, you need another prefix in the 4th word!

Comment: In addition to the third, yeah. All those after the second, to be precise.